# SQL query takes 20 minutes to finish and only contains 1300 rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has a unique string column and a department description. The length of the unique string column represents the department hierarchy so 4 character length is the lowest level while 2 character length the highest.

My goal is to create new variables so I can show the hierarchy levels and corresponding department descriptions for each row and use these new columns as filters

My SQL code is working; however, it takes more than 20 minutes to generate results for a 1300 row table.

Is there a better way to optimize this query? Note that I’m only using one table and creating multiple copies to create the final version that I’d like to achieve.

```
   m.UniqueDescription as "Department Code",
   m.DepartmentDescription as "Department",
   Left(m.UniqueDescription,2) as "Level 2 Hierarchy",
   Left(m.UniqueDescription,3) as "Level 3 Hierarchy",
   Left(m.UniqueDescription,4) as "Level 4 Hierarchy",
   l2. DepartmentDescription as "L2 Department",
   l3. DepartmentDescription as "L3 Department",
   l4. DepartmentDescription as "L4 Department"


From department_table  m

LEFT JOIN department_table  l2
    ON Left(m.UniqueDescription,2)  = l2.UniqueDescription

LEFT JOIN department_table  l3
    ON Left(m.UniqueDescription,3)  = l3.UniqueDescription

LEFT JOIN department_table  l4
    ON Left(m.UniqueDescription,4)  = l4.UniqueDescription"
```

Below is the output that I would like to achieve:

[Table Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNWjY.png)

Comment: It's probably a good idea to learn some database design.  Where are your `ID`s?

Comment: Other than stating that the design of your tables is not very good nobody can really offer much help here. We would need to see the actual table definition, including indexes. However, you have largely crippled your ability to utilize indexes with all those LEFT functions.

Comment: The number of rows returned isn't a direct correlation to performance. Just because only 1300 are returned to the client, that doesn't mean *only* 1300 was fetched from disk or memory. it could be in the millions. As @SeanLange stated, your use of `left()` makes your query non SARG-able which means you'll have to scan every table most likely. [Start here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/) for a list of things needed to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, the structure and missing of numeric IDs is not a good practice

Check for index creation.

Do not use functions on the left side of your `ON` or `WHERE` clauses, it doesn't allow to the execution planner to index those columns.

Instead of `FUNCTION(LeftTable.Column) = value` use `LeftTable.Column = INVERSE_FUNCTION(value)`